# JSF - how to properly use loops [c:forEach vs ui:repeat]

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to create a generic pageable table that will display any entity from database. I'm using annotations and reflection for that purpose. On the java side everything works fine, however I can't manage to create a view for my table. I tried two approaches, with c:forEach and ui:repeat:

**Requirements for the view**:

- Fixed amount of records should be displayed on each page (eg. 10)
- Components for browsing and editing table columns should be generated automatically based on viewed field type (field annotated in hibernate entity)
- Additional column with actions should be added (removing, saving, filtering, adding entities)
- Additional row for filtering and adding fresh entities should be added above table header
- Each column has to be sortable

**c:forEach approach problem**:

When changing between pages that have different number of records, then **proper records are displayed** but number of rows is the same like on the previous page. If **previous page had less records than next page will have less records** than it should have and if **previous page had more records than next page will have more records** than it should have. However when I refresh the whole site on the given page everything renders properly.

[image: When changing from page with more records to page with less]

[image: When changing from page with less records to page with more]

On the first picture you can see, when I go to the last page unnecessary records are generated to match previous page size. On the second picture, page size is truncated to the last page size.

**Table body code**:

```
<tbody class="lot">
    <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.wflBean.searchProvider.cells}" var="row" varStatus="rowStatus">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="#{row.cells}" var="cell" varStatus="cellStatus">
                <td style="text-align: #{cell.alignment}; vertical-align: bottom;">
                    <h:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.wflBean.editEntity}" value="Edit" styleClass="none"
                                   rendered="#{cc.attrs.wflBean.isExternalEditSupported and cc.attrs.wflBean.canEdit}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{cc.attrs.wflBean.currentEntity}" value="#{cell.entity}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
                    <!--TODO: cellIndex will not work properly for more then 10 columns/rows-->
                    <comp:pagableTableCell wflBean="#{cc.attrs.wflBean}" cell="#{cell}"
                                           cellIndex="#{cellStatus.index}#{rowStatus.index}"
                                           canEdit="#{not cc.attrs.wflBean.isExternalEditSupported and cc.attrs.wflBean.canEdit}"/>
                </td>
            </c:forEach>
            ...CODE FOR ADDING ADDITIONAL ACCTIONS...
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

pagableTableCell is a custom component that renders proper component for editing cell value it is done with *c:choose*/*c:when*/*c:otherwise* tags. When changing page, the cells are retrieved. Its done during *RESTORE_VIEW* and *RENDER_RESPONSE* phase. Cells for new page are **recalculated and returned properly** during *RENDER_RESPONSE* phase. Also, I read that *c:forEach* tag is evaluated during build view phase but I don't see what *javax.faces.event.PhaseId* is that? Page is set by another custom component and it is done properly right before *RENDER_RESPONSE* phase.

**ui:repeat approach problem**:

With this approach I replaced *c:forEach* with *ui:repeat* and *c:choose*/*c:when*/*c:otherwise* with *ui:fragment* but then, I can't evaluate EL expression within id attribute, to make it unique, for date component that you can see on images above. Unique id is required for date component to work properly. Is there any way to manually generate component id when using *ui:repeat*?

Overall I don't know how should I approach this problem. c:forEach seems to work better for me, at least table is usable. Could you advise me how to fix one of this problems?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason why you're building the HTML markup yourself instead of using `h:dataTable`?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I thought about it. But my concern was if I could create two header rows. One for filtering and adding new entities and the second one for column headers. Is it possible? Another problem that I see is that now I got two lists one with column descriptors and one with entities (rows) I do not know how many columns will be in the table, its all generic. Maybe I could use dataTable but then I would have to use some kind of loop anyway to create columns.